# Named lists inside list, how to access elements containing certain pattern in name?

Tags: r, string, list

I have a list of named lists, called `cci`. I want to extract the element whose name contains a `001` at the end, so in the subsequent case the eleventh entry. `cci` is a large list with more than 50`000 entries. Any suggestions on how to deal with this? Many thanks in advance.

```
> length(cci)
[1] 51786

> str(cci[1])
List of 1
 $ 1310731:List of 12
  ..$ 1310657: int 44
  ..$ 1310754: int 609
  ..$ 1310019: int 661
  ..$ 1310020: int 770
  ..$ 1310118: int 82
  ..$ 1310119: int 1014
  ..$ 1310732: int 743
  ..$ 1310189: int 412
  ..$ 1310190: int 511
  ..$ 1310192: int 269
  ..$ 1310001: int 1491
  ..$ 1310674: int 64
```

Comment: okay, got it.. phew... when I asked this question I already sat on this issue like 2 hours. `grepl('001$',names(cci[[1]]))`. I guess I will use lapply to extract this info from all lists in `cci`...

Comment: `cci[[1]][[which(grepl('001$',names(cci[[1]])))]]`. WTF, R...